# how to get next month date from today using Time

Tags: ruby

I need to generate next month date from today. Should I manuallt check if month == 12 and add +1 to d.year or there is easy solution?
Time class did strange math:

```
>> d = Time.now
=> 2015-12-03 15:15:36 +0300 
>> d.month
=> 12
>> d.month.next
=> 13
```

Comment: @hoijui, no, it isn't. See Stefan's answer.

Comment: Yes, @Stefan's answer is bang-on, but next time consider waiting longer before selecting an answer. For one, a quick selection may discourage other answers, answers that might be interesting, if not better. Also, be mindfull that some readers still preparing answers may be disappointed to see the check mark flash on so quickly. There's no rush.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Date` has a method [`next_month`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-next_month):

```
require 'date'
Date.today                  #=> #<Date: 2015-12-03 ((2457360j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
Date.today.next_month       #=> #<Date: 2016-01-03 ((2457391j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
Date.today.next_month.month #=> 1
```

To convert a `Time` instance to a `Date`, use [`to_date`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Time.html#method-i-to_date).

Comment: it fits perfect. Because I have to use date-picker, also needs to calculate year. Now can parse to next month from today and get day, year and month. Thank you all.

Comment: ...or `Date.today >> n` for `n` months hence.

Comment: ...and `Date.now << n` for `n` months ago. Both `Date#<<` and `Date#>>` permit `n` to be negative (so `Date.new << -1` is one month hence).

Answer (score 1):

Yes add+1 
but do (this month + 1)%12

```
if ( thisMonth == 12)
   nextMonth = 1;
else
   nextMonth = thisMonth+1;
```

This is just to give an idea
I did not see for any edge cases yet

Comment: In Ruby, variable names should be written in `snake_case`, the semicolons and parentheses are superfluous, but an `end` is mandatory. Apart from that, why didn't you provide an example utilizing the aforementioned modulo operator?

Comment: In addition to the missing `end`, this does not return a date. I didn't downvote this answer (and I rarely downvote) because I wanted readers to see that it received an upvote, which is utterally bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

there are two commonly used possible solutions:

1: `Date.today+1.month` OR for month only `(Date.today+1.month).month`

2: `Date.today.next_month` OR for month only `Date.today.next_month.month`

Comment: [`Integer#month`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Integer.html#method-i-month) requires ActiveSupport and you would probably write `1.month.from_now`